# Number of 10-tuples satisfying this equation

Tags: combinatorics

The question is:

Find the number of 10-tuples ($a_1,a_2,...,a_{10}$) of integers such that $|a_1|≤ 1$ and

$a^2_1 + a^2_2 + a^2_3 +···+ a_{10}^2 −a_1a_2 −a_2a_3 −a_3a_4 −···−a_9a_{10} −a_{10}a_1 = 2$.

The official solution is given [here](http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/uploads/crmo-2013-solutions-1) (scroll down to the 4th question).
Can someone explain me this solution?
Especially the part where they say

"Note that if $a_i −a_{i+1} = ±2$ for some $i = 1,...,10,$ then $a_j −a_{j+1} = 0$ for all $j \not = i$ which contradicts the equality $$\sum_{i=1}^{10} (a_i-a_{i+1})=0$$

So I don't get when was the equality established and why must $a_j −a_{j+1} = 0$ if  $a_i −a_{i+1} = ±2$?

I request anyone interested in answering this question to write an answer with sufficient information and not just hints to solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_i-a_{i+1}=\pm 2$, then $$(a_i-a_{i+1})^2+\sum _{j\neq i}(a_j-a_{j+1})^2=4+\sum _{j\neq i}(a_j-a_{j+1})^2=4,$$ then $\sum _{j\neq i}(a_j-a_{j+1})^2=0$..But you are summing non negative numbers, so $a_j-a_{j+1}=0$ for $j\neq i$. Now, notice that $$\sum _{k=1}^{10}(a_k-a_{k+1})=a_1-a_{11}=a_1-a_1=0,$$ but we have also that $$\sum _{k=1}^{10}(a_k-a_{k+1})=(a_i-a_{i+1})+\sum _{k\neq i}(a_k-a_{k+1})=\pm 2,$$ so $\pm 2=0$ which is a contradiction.

Hope it helps.